# SignalR Hub OnDisconnectedAsync Method Does Not Get Hit in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

Here I am trying to remove `ConnectionId` from connected connectedId list `UserHandler.ConnectedUser` in `OnDisconnectedAsync` method of my hub.
But the problem is that when ever user gets logout from application or close that window the `OnDisconnectedAsync` method on hub does not get hit.

Any help with my code will be grate. Thank you.

Below is my hub

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public List<string> SendingUserList = new List<string>();
    public async Task SendMessage(string to, string message)
    {
        var senderConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        SendingUserList.Add(to);
        SendingUserList.Add(senderConnectionId);
        foreach (var connectionId in SendingUserList)
        {
            await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
    }
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        Clients.All.SendAsync("ReciveUser", UserHandler.UserName, Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception e)
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedUser.Remove(Context.ConnectionId));
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
    }      
}
public static class UserHandler
{
    public static HashSet<string> ConnectedUser = new HashSet<string>();
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my remaining code

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        UserHandler.UserName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();
        hubConnection.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", BroadcastMessage);
        hubConnection.On<string,string>("ReciveUser", RefreshUserList);

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();

        StateHasChanged();
    }
    private void RefreshUserList(string connectedUserId, string connectionId )
    {
        UserHandler.ConnectedUser.Add(connectionId);
        connectedUserList = UserHandler.ConnectedUser;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    private void BroadcastMessage(string message)
    {
        var encodedMsg = $"{message}";
        messages.Add(encodedMsg);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to implement the `IAsyncDisposable` interface in the Hub's consumer (Razor Component), like this:

```
@implements IAsyncDisposable
```

Add these methods:

```
public void Dispose()
    {
       
        hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
```

Now, when you close the client's page the OnDisconnectedAsync method will be called.

Comment: Why isn't this implemented by the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub?